# Unable to find out how a content type node is getting themed

Tags: nodes, theming, uri

I have a drupal 7 installation with a paid template which I am trying to tweak. The template has a demo installation, which has a `content-type` named 'Team'.

So I created a bunch of content with type as Team. Now if I create a `Basic Page` content and in the `URL Alias` if I give '**content/team**', then it shows a grid view of all the team content I created (each team members photo, name & designation with a read more button).

There is a `node--view--team.tpl` file available in the codebase.

My problem starts when I try to rename the content-type called `Team` to 'Students`(machine name was also changed to`students`). After renaming I renamed the tpl file to`node--view--students.tpl`. In the URL alias, if I give any url other than '**content/team**', all I get is an empty page. If I change the URL alias to '**content/team**' - everything works!!

This is driving me mad, I know I cannot get a complete answer since I am tweaking a custom theme, but any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this before; it's the result of some bad practices commonly used by the commercial Wordpress—ehem, wait, I mean, Drupal—themers.

The culprit code is probably in a function in `template.php` or similar. Try searching the entire theme codebase for "team" - if you are on a Unix system you can use the grep command like this

```
grep -r "team" /path/to/theme
```

This might help you find the dirty function.